# Minha hospedagem nao conecta o banco

Tags: php

Ao upar o banco de dados aparece isso:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function prepare() on a non-object in

como posso resolver , para poder conectar?
pois local funciona normalmente.

```
 <?php
  require_once ('./funcao/conecta.php');
  $conn = conecta();
  $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `lojao`.`categorias` ORDER BY nome_categoria ASC");
  $sql->execute();
  $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  while ($linha = $sql->fetch()) {
      $categoriaid = $linha['id_categoria'];
      $nomecategoria = $linha['nome_categoria'];
      echo'<div align = "left">';
          echo'<li>
      <a href = "index.php?idCat=' . $categoriaid . '">' . $nomecategoria . '</a>
      </li>';
  }
echo '</div>
</div id="link"><div>
</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Sua conexão não é válida, segundo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, são dois erros diferentes aí.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Tentou conectar, e a conexão demorou. Provavelmente é problema de rede. Desenhe aí como o "localmente" faz para chegar no banco de dados (nome, IP), e como o servidor faz o mesmo caminho. Isso pode clarear.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Como a conexão falhou, tudo o que se segue falha. Tentou chamar o método `prepare()` no objeto `$conn`, mas pelo jeito o erro faz com que o objeto não tenha sido criado, por isso não tem esse método.